# Use the apply function in Pandas to use a Regex count per row

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a Pandas df that has this structure:

```
Store CID          UnitsOH                                        Count

1   23095   17_17_17_16_16_15_15_15_15_15_13_12_10_9_8_7_7...   15982

23101   6_6_5_5_5_5_4_3_3_3_7_6_5_5_5_5_5_5_3_2_2_5_5_...   15982

23117   6_6_6_6_6_6_6_6_6_6_6_6_5_5_5_4_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_...   15982

23161   6_6_6_6_6_6_6_6_6_6_6_5_5_5_4_4_4_4_4_3_3_3_3_...   15982

23222   5_5_5_5_5_5_5_5_4_4_4_4_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_7_...   15982
```

I need to count how many times a specific Pattern happens on that "Units OH" column.  For example, need to count how many times every row has any positive number followed by 0.  I used a "_" separator when I concatenated the field, so I'm looking for a Pattern of '**[1-9]**[0]__' (Sorry about the format... first post here and don't understand how to format the text correctly).

I used this code to create that last column called 'Count':

```
ConcatOH['Count'] = ConcatOH['Units_OH'].str.count('_[1-9]_[0]_').sum()
```

However, as you can see, it seems that the the count is counting through the entire dataframe and giving me the same count for every row.    How can I do the count by row only.  is there an axis=0 argument I could use somewhere or can somebody help me with how to use the apply method to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.sum()` at the end of `ConcatOH['Units_OH'].str.count('_[1-9]_[0]_').sum()`

`ConcatOH['Units_OH'].str.count('_[1-9]_[0]_')` returns a series and then your summing it to get an int and that is assigned to `ConcatOH['Count']` hence why you have the same value for each row

Your basically doing

`ConcatOH['Count'] = 15982`

You want

`ConcatOH['Count'] = ConcatOH['Units_OH'].str.count('_[1-9]_[0]_')`

Answer (score 0):

Javier, do you mean something like this:

```
import re
ConcatOH['Units_OH'].apply(lambda x: len(re.findall('_[\d+]_0', x)))
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't try this, because the previous answer by ksooklall worked great with minimum changes to my code.  What I did try was the regex expression that you had here, but is not working correctly because I need to count only when a 0 follows a POSITIVE NUMBER.   When I try your expression, it is counting every time a 0 follows another 0 as well (ie, when the text begins with 0_0_0_0...